# Find most common combinations and how many times they occur

Tags: excel, google-sheets

In the example below I want to search each unique order and then the items in that order. From that I would like to extract the most common items that are ordered together and how many times they occur together. This is just a sample. I am doing this with a file with 20,000 rows.

Sorry, I haven't earned enough points to embed the photo. It's in the link below.

Screenshot of the example

[image]

Comment: If possible, can you also share a desired output? Thank you

Comment: what if someone orders "soda water taco" combo and another one orders "water taco soda" combo? It's kinda same combo but none of the provided answers tackle this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this formula** to get the occurrences with one formula one cell.

```
=ArrayFormula({ "Occurrences",$B$1:$F$1; 
     QUERY({COUNTIF(
 B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E&F2:F,
 "="&QUERY({ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE($B$2:$F),ROWS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F))-1,COLUMNS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F)))}, " Select  Col1 ")&
     QUERY({ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE($B$2:$F),ROWS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F))-1,COLUMNS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F)))}, " Select  Col2 ")&
     QUERY({ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE($B$2:$F),ROWS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F))-1,COLUMNS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F)))}, " Select  Col3 ")&
     QUERY({ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE($B$2:$F),ROWS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F))-1,COLUMNS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F)))}, " Select  Col4 ")&
     QUERY({ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE($B$2:$F),ROWS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F))-1,COLUMNS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F)))}, " Select  Col5 "))
           }, "Select Col1 where Col1 <> 0 "),
            ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE($B$2:$F),ROWS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F))-1,COLUMNS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F))) })
```

[image]

### Option 02

```
=ArrayFormula({ "Occurrences",$B$1:$F$1; 
     QUERY({ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(COUNTIF(
            FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:F), "",9^9 )),
        "="&FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE($B$2:$F),ROWS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F))-1,COLUMNS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F)))), "",9^9 ))),
     COUNTA(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE($B$2:$F),ROWS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F))-1,COLUMNS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F)))), "",9^9 ))),1)
           }, "Select Col1 where Col1 <> 0 "),
            ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE($B$2:$F),ROWS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F))-1,COLUMNS(UNIQUE($B$2:$F))) })
```

[image]

*I hope that helped* ^_^

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much for taking the time to do this!

Comment: unless someone orders reversed combo...

Answer (score 1):

try this and notice the blue cells:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(E2:I="",,ROW(E2:I)&"♠♦"&PROPER(E2:I)&"♥")), "♦")), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col1 <> '♠' group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "♠")), 
 "select count(Col2),Col2 where Col2 is not null group by Col2 order by count(Col2) desc"), 
 "select Col1,'♥',Col2"), "offset 1", )),,9^9)), "♥")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Alternate Solution (with Helper Columns):

Though the other solution posted works I've figured this will not count it in the same combination if the items are interchanged. For example:

[image]

This will be counted as 1 for each even they are the same combination.

**So here's another solution if you don't mind using helper columns:**

**1.)** Use this formula in 1 column to combine all items in the order:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, SORT(TRANSPOSE(E2:I2), 1, TRUE))
```

Drag down to column.

[image]

This uses `SORT()` function to first sort the items alphabetically before using `TEXTJOIN()` function to concatenate the items into one cell. This is so that it will not matter even if the items are interchanged.

**2.)** Use the UNIQUE() function to remove the duplicates.

```
=UNIQUE(K2:K15)
```

[image]

**3.)** Use the `COUNTIF()` to count the number of occurences. Then the `IF()` to only apply it for rows that are not blank. Then `ArrayFormula()` so there's no need to drag down the formula to the column you just need to input in the first row.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(L2:L<>"",COUNTIF(K2:K,L2:L),""))
```

**Final Result:**

[image]

**Limitation:**
This can't count as same combination if the total order is not the same. For example:

[image]

They will be counted as 1 each.

**References:**

- [Concatenate and Alphabetize](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/dfmexe/concatenate_and_alphabetize/)
- [If Not Empty](https://www.statology.org/google-sheets-if-not-empty/)

Answer (score 0):

Solution with PowerQuery

You can add as many Item-Colums you want (Columnname must have the    word "Item" in it -> "Item 6", "Item 7", "Last Item", "My Item",    "Special Item" ...)

You do not have to adjust any range in a cell formula

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(
    Source,
    "Combination",
        each Text.Combine( 
           List.Sort(
                List.Transform(
                    List.Select(
                        Table.ColumnNames(Source),
                        each Text.Contains(_,"Item")
                    )
                    , (col)=> Record.Field(_, col)
                )
            ), 
            "; "), type text
        ),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Inserted Merged Column", {"Combination"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Count", Order.Descending}})
in
#"Sorted Rows"
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's a tough one with multiple combinations and order sequence matters. A not so complete answer for only the first two items would be:

*Formulas Layout*
[image]

In Cell K2 `=E2&" "&F2`
In Cell M2 `=COUNTIF($E:$I,L2)`
In Cell O2 `=COUNTIFS($K:$K,$L2&" "&O$1)`

That would only add up the first two items in each order in a matrix style layout and I added conditional formatting for viewing higher numbers in the matrix.